# Iterating with delay in Framer

Tags: framerjs

I have a text field where I want to push out one word at a time. The words are in an array. The delay between words to displayed is set to 1 sec. The first word is shown 2 sec. Hence the weird double statements.

```
msgArray = [
    ["Hello", "World"], 
    ["89:23", "Tom Eriksen","Scooores!!"],
    ["Overtime", "about to", "start"]]

printMessageLoop =  (msgArray, target) ->
target.text = msgArray[0]
timeToRead = 1
Utils.delay timeToRead, () ->
    for i in [1..msgArray.length-1]
        Utils.delay timeToRead*i,() ->
            target.text = msgArray[i]
            print "i="+i #debugging purpose
```

When I call `printMessageLoop(msgArray[2])` the `target` displays the first word correctly, but two last is "undefined". The printout says:

```
printMessageLoop(msgArray[2])

»i=3
»i=3
```

It seems like when the line `target.text = msgArray[i]` is executed that `i` is set to the last `i`. That is i++ = 3

Why? And how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

call `do (i) ->` before the delay to make sure the current value of i is forwarded into future instructions

```
printMessageLoop =  (msgArray, target) ->
target.text = msgArray[0]
timeToRead = target.text.length/20 * readingSpeed
Utils.delay timeToRead, () ->
    for i in [1..msgArray.length-1]
        do (i) ->
            Utils.delay timeToRead*i,() ->
                target.text = msgArray[i    ]
                print "i="+i
                timeToRead = target.text.length/20 * readingSpeed
```